# Missing flow in type narrowing with "unknown" datatype in typescript

Tags: typescript

I was playing with the unknown type. The minimal example is:

```
let value: unknown;
if (value === undefined || value === null || value === '') {
  typeof value;    //  ""|null|undefined  fine
} else if (typeof value === 'object') {
  typeof value;     // object | null  huh? 
}
```

Is this a design limitation or a bug in typescript? I could not find something like that in the issue tracker.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going to call this a design limitation/missing feature: TypeScript doesn't currently have [subtraction types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4183) or [negated types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4196), and although there was at some point work being done here ([microsoft/TypeScript#29317](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317)), it was [shelved](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317#issuecomment-488825134).  That means there's no general way to take two types `A` and `B` and represent the type "everything assignable to `A` but not to `B`", a.k.a., `A - B` or `A \ B` or `A & not B`, etc.  If `A` and `B` happen to be union types where every member of `B` is a member of `A` then you can use a conditional type like [`Exclude<A, B>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetu), but that *only* works for union types.

Since `unknown` is not a union type, there is no way in TypeScript to represent the type `unknown & not (undefined | null | "")`, which is what you want the compiler to narrow `value` to in the `else` clause.  No narrowing happens at all in the `else` clause, and `value` stays `unknown`. Sorry.

Since `value` is still of type `unknown` in the `else` clause, the check `typeof value === 'object'` can only narrow from `unknown` to the types where `typeof value === 'object'` is true: that's `object | null`.

---

That might not be satisfying: *why* is the `unknown` type treated as a non-union, as opposed to being represented internally as, say, `{} | null | undefined` or `object | string | number | boolean | null | undefined`?  After all, you'd be hard-pressed to find a value of type `unknown` which is not assignable to one of those other types (`"hello"` is assignable to `{}`, for example).  And indeed, if you change the annotated type of `value` to `object | string | number | boolean | null | undefined`, you'll get the behavior you want:

```
let value: object | string | number | boolean | null | undefined;
if (value === undefined || value === null || value === '') {
    typeof value;    //  ""|null|undefined 
} else if (typeof value === 'object') {
    typeof value;     // object
}
```

So why doesn't `unknown` just act like that all the time?  The closest thing to a definitive answer comes in a [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27418#issuecomment-426354612) to a related issue by one of the TS leads:

> There was a long internal discussion over whether or not we even needed `unknown`, because it has an identical domain to `{} | null | undefined` - it was even proposed to just write that as a type alias in `lib.d.ts`. But we explicitly wanted a type that *didn't* distribute over conditional types because that expansion typically made things worse rather than better.

Having `unknown` treated like a union causes weird downstream behavior with [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).  Any language feature that slices types into unions of subtypes has observable effects, some of which might not be what you want to see.  I've seen people stumble into the fact that `boolean` is actually defined as the union `true | false` and that it splits into pieces when people expect it not to.  It's a tricky thing in general, and any choice made tends to be a trade-off that leaves at least some people unhappy.

---

In your case you could either change the annotated type of `value` from `unknown` to a better-behaved union... or, if you can't change it, you could use an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) to "prepare" `value` for the control-flow analysis to follow:

```
function toUnion(
    x: unknown
): asserts x is object | string | number | boolean | null | undefined { }
```

And then you call `toUnion(value)` before the check:

```
let value: unknown;
toUnion(value); // does nothing at runtime but transforms value to the union type
if (value === undefined || value === null || value === '') {
    typeof value;    //  ""|null|undefined 
} else if (typeof value === 'object') {
    typeof value;     // object
}
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFOBVM8wAoBQj+IAeAXIuANZhwDuYOAlKQIYDOLApgE5QtGIy84AIwBW7aIgA+iFlE4wwAcymIwIALZCuKoXDgAbdkyTS1+-SvAATdsAXsriAN6IAvjhyGoiAG5N9IOykFFS0ANw4KOiYWH4B7PRhiDgwwIix-oGIALy5ZGA2dmAOUtJxWbnZqiDmpb6Z7Dl5AOTN9M54BFAAngAO7HBp5exJBAD0Y-gARFOSZvqS1rb2jjiuiOz6HPxpWD39g-XxTVXNwmLQbR0EyH0DQw2j45Pn4lBrHkA)